# How to use custom components in react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, next.js, remarkjs, chakra-ui

Context: I have a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) site with [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/). I have some user provided markdown content that is fetched from an external source (say, GitHub `README.md` for a repo) at runtime.

Now, by default, [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) (based on [remarkjs](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark)) uses the HTML `<img>` tag for markdown images (`![]()`). I want to use the [new `<Image />` component released in Next.js 10](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) in the user provided markdown. Additionally, I also would like to replace other tags with corresponding Chakra UI components.

How do I go about doing this?

**SOLUTION**

```js
// utils/parser.tsx

import Image from 'next/image';

export default function ImageRenderer({ src, alt }) {
  return <Image src={src} alt={alt} unsized />;
}
```

and then in the required page:

```js
//pages/readme.tsx

import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import imageRenderer from '../utils/parser';

// `readme` is sanitised markdown that comes from getServerSideProps
export default function Module({ readme }) {
  return <ReactMarkdown allowDangerousHtml={true} renderers={{ image: imageRenderer }} children={readme} />
}
```

same for other elements...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

react-markdown lets you define your own renderers. I have recently did something similar. I want to use figure and figurecaption elements. So, I have created my own image renderer react component.

**Component**

```
export default function ImageRenderer(props) {
    const imageSrc = props.src;
    const altText = props.alt;
    return (
        <figure className="wp-block-image size-large is-resized">
            <img
                data-loading="lazy" 
                data-orig-file={imageSrc}
                data-orig-size="1248,533"
                data-comments-opened="1"
                data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}"
                data-image-title="builtin_vs_dotnetwarp"
                data-image-description=""
                data-medium-file={imageSrc + "?w=300"}
                data-large-file={imageSrc + "?w=750"}
                src={imageSrc + "?w=10241"}
                alt={altText}
                srcSet={imageSrc + "?w=1024 1024w, " + imageSrc + "?w=705 705w, " + imageSrc + "?w=150 150w, " + imageSrc + "?w=300 300w, " + imageSrc + "?w=768 768w, " + imageSrc + "?1248w"}
                sizes="(max-width: 707px) 100vw, 707px" />
            <figcaption style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{altText}</figcaption>
        </figure>
    );
}
```

**And I use that renderer as below**

```
<ReactMarkdown source={blogResponse.data.content} escapeHtml={false} renderers={{ "code": CodeBlockRenderer, "image": ImageRenderer }} />
```

renderers={{ "code": CodeBlockRenderer, "image": ImageRenderer }} is where you mention custom renderers.

Comment: but  I still don't get how to set custom Heading `h1...h6` tags.

Comment: I never had to modify headings. Can you share your code?

Comment: I don't necessarily have to but I want to use Chakra UI's Heading component. I looked in to the renderer docs and found that it has a `heading` option but I don't know how to differentiate between h1 and h2. can you point me to better renderer docs?

repo:https://github.com/maximousblk/next-nest-test

Comment: For heading the props will have a property called **level** which you can use to differentiate among h1, h2 ..h6.

You can find the sample code here. https://github.com/Dhrutara/blogs.dhrutara.com.blogs/tree/main/react-markdown/src/components